# Congruence induced by a subset.

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations, monoid

Consider the additive monoid of natural numbers and calculate the congruence generated by $\{(2,3)\}$.
I know the answer is that the congruence has 3 classes which are $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$, and 
the rest.

Also I have been given the definition that the congruence on $A$ generated by a set $R$ is the smallest congruence on $A \times A$ which contains $R$.

So if anybody could help tell me how the answer was calculated that would really be appreciated.

Comment: You can get any even number (bigger than 0) as a sum $\sum 2$, and any odd number bigger than 1 as a sum $3+\sum 2$.

Comment: I've found an answer here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464653/smallest-congruence-relation-generated-by-a-set